# Is it possible to enable Tiles View for icons on the Windows 7 desktop?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons, layout

Is it possible to enable Tiles View for icons on the Windows 7 desktop?

You can get the same thing in Windows Explorer by going to a folder and selecting "Tiles" for the icon view option. The Windows 7 desktop is just another Explorer view isn't it? There must be a hidden registry key setting somewhere that lets me set the view mode of the desktop, but I can't find any articles online that describe it.

I used to be able to do this using D-Color XP on Windows XP, but that utility doesn't work on my Windows 7 64-bit system (contrary to what some blog articles mention).

Answer (score -1):

Make the icon names blank and toggle off automatic-grid-sorting of icons. Then arrange the icons like you want